# Expressing the likelihood of the multivariate normal

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, likelihood, multivariate-normal-distribution, conditioning

I have two multivariate normal samples:

$\boldsymbol{X^{(1)}=\left(
\begin{matrix} 
\boldsymbol{Y^{(1)}}\\\boldsymbol{Z^{(1)}} 
\end{matrix}\right)}$
and 
$\boldsymbol{X^{(2)}=\left(
\begin{matrix} 
\boldsymbol{Y^{(2)}}\\\boldsymbol{Z^{(2)}} 
\end{matrix}\right)}$, where $\boldsymbol{Y^{(i)}}$ has dimension $q$ and $\boldsymbol{Z^{(i)}}$ has dimension $r$ where $p=q+r$.

Here, $\boldsymbol{X^{(i)}}$ ~ 
$N_p
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{\mu_y^{(i)}}\\\boldsymbol{\mu_z^{(i)}} 
\end{bmatrix},
\Sigma
\end{bmatrix}
$, where
$\Sigma=
\begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma_{qq}&\Sigma_{qr}\\
\Sigma_{rq}&\Sigma_{rr}
\end{bmatrix}$.  The end goal is to find the likelihood ratio criterion for testing $H_0: \boldsymbol{\mu_z^{(1)}=\mu_z^{(2)}}$ vs. $H_a: \boldsymbol{\mu_z^{(1)}\neq\mu_z^{(2)}}$ given
$\boldsymbol{\mu_y^{(1)}=\mu_y^{(2)}}$ on the basis of a sample of $n_i$ observations from $\boldsymbol{X^{(i)}}$.

I am trying to figure out how to express the likelihood of $\boldsymbol{X^{(i)}}$ here.  It is not appropriate to test these hypotheses using just the marginal distribution of $\boldsymbol{Z^{(i)}}$ as $\boldsymbol{Z^{(i)}}$ and $\boldsymbol{Y^{(i)}}$ are not independent.

My questions are:

1) Would it be appropriate to express the likelihood of $\boldsymbol{X^{(i)}}$ as the multiplication of the marginal density of $\boldsymbol{Y^{(i)}}$ and the conditional density of $\boldsymbol{Z^{(i)}}$ given $\boldsymbol{Y^{(i)}}$?

2) If this is ok to do would it then be ok to express the likelihood of observing $\boldsymbol{X^{(1)}}$ and $\boldsymbol{X^{(2)}}$ by simply multiplying them together because $\boldsymbol{X^{(1)}}$ is independent of $\boldsymbol{X^{(2)}}$?

3) Now, given 1) and 2), we have a way of expressing the likelihood of $\boldsymbol{X^{(1)}}$ and $\boldsymbol{X^{(2)}}$ jointly and we may thus maximize the likelihood under the null and alternative to complete the problem?

Comment: yes to all questions. I am slightly puzzled by the hypothesis being "conditional" on a constraint on the [non-random] parameters.

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, I was confused about that too.  I have edited the question statement slightly to be what I think it is supposed to reflect.